Filter the Excel data based on certain condition and copy the data to next Excel sheet
I have two Excel files TEST.csv and TEST.xlsm.
The path for the both files is C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\MACRO\TEST2.

I want to copy the data from the .csv file to an .xlsm file based on a filter condition. Using the time intervals in column B of the .csv file, I need to filter the data and copy it to the next Excel file's sheet called Sheet1.
The data is recorded at 5-second intervals, but I only need the data at 10-minute intervals. How to filter the data? Any help would be appreciated.



Date
Time(PC)
Time(MEMS)
Water Level(m)
Voltage1[v]
Voltage2[v]




2024/9/1
0:00:00
0:00:54
1.494
12.1
0


2024/9/1
0:00:05
0:00:59
1.496
12.2
0


2024/9/1
0:00:10
0:01:04
1.501
12.1
0


2024/9/1
0:00:15
0:01:09
1.491
12
0


2024/9/1
0:00:20
0:01:14
1.491
12.2
0


2024/9/1
0:00:25
0:01:19
1.496
12.1
0


2024/9/1
0:00:30
0:01:24
1.5
12.2
0


2024/9/1
0:00:35
0:01:29
1.498
12.1
0


2024/9/1
0:00:40
0:01:34
1.496
12.1
0


2024/9/1
0:00:45
0:01:39
1.495
12.1
0


2024/9/1
0:00:50
0:01:44
1.492
12
0


2024/9/1
0:00:55
0:01:49
1.498
12.1
0


2024/9/1
0:01:00
0:01:54
1.495
12.1
0


2024/9/1
0:01:05
0:01:59
1.497
12.1
0



My code:
Sub FilterAndCopyDataIn10MinuteIntervals()
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim targetWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceFilePath As String
    Dim targetFilePath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim currentTime As Variant
    
    ' Define file paths
    sourceFilePath = "C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\MACRO\TEST2\TEST.csv"
    targetFilePath = "C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\MACRO\TEST2\TEST.xlsm"
    
    ' Open source workbook (CSV)
    Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(sourceFilePath)
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWB.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Open target workbook (XLSM)
    Set targetWB = Workbooks.Open(targetFilePath)
    Set targetSheet = targetWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Clear previous data in the target sheet
    targetSheet.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Find the last row with data in the source sheet (column B)
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    targetRow = 1  ' Initialize the target row for copying to Sheet1
    
    ' Loop through each row and filter the time interval from column B
    For currentRow = 2 To lastRow
        currentTime = sourceSheet.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
        
        ' Check if the value in column B is a valid time
        If IsDate(currentTime) Then
            currentTime = TimeValue(currentTime)
            
            ' Check if the time matches the 10-minute interval (00:00:00, 00:10:00, etc.)
            If (Hour(currentTime) Mod 10 = 0 And Minute(currentTime) = 0 And Second(currentTime) = 0) Then
                ' Copy the entire row where the time in column B matches the interval
                sourceSheet.Rows(currentRow).Copy
                targetSheet.Rows(targetRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                targetRow = targetRow + 1  ' Move to the next target row in Sheet1
            End If
        End If
    Next currentRow
    
    ' Save and close workbooks
    targetWB.Save
    
    MsgBox "Data filtered and copied in 10-minute intervals."
End Sub


Give a try to If (Minute(currentTime) Mod 10 = 0 And Second(currentTime) = 0) Then

Your code is good enough. Some minor changes in your code will give you the result.
Dim currentTime As Variant
' It will be Date data type
Dim currentTime As Date

Another change in calculating 10 minutes interval. DateAdd function is applicable in this context. 10 minutes= 600 seconds, so next interval time will be
dim NextTime as date
NextTime = DateAdd("s",CurrentTime,600)

and your If clause for checking 10 minutes interval will be changed to
If (CurrentTime = NextTime) 

With this changes finally your code will be
Sub FilterAndCopyDataIn10MinuteIntervals()
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim targetWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceFilePath As String
    Dim targetFilePath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim currentTime As Date 'Variant
    
    ' Define file paths
    sourceFilePath = "C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\MACRO\TEST2\TEST.csv"
    targetFilePath = "C:\Users\WS035\Desktop\MACRO\TEST2\TEST.xlsm"
    
    ' Open source workbook (CSV)
    Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(sourceFilePath)
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWB.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Open target workbook (XLSM)
    Set targetWB = Workbooks.Open(targetFilePath)
    Set targetSheet = targetWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Clear previous data in the target sheet
    targetSheet.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Find the last row with data in the source sheet (column B)
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    targetRow = 1  ' Initialize the target row for copying to Sheet1
    
    ' Loop through each row and filter the time interval from column B
    ' Additional code for variable initialization
    Dim NextTime As Date
    CurrentTime = sourceSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value
    NextTime = DateAdd("s", 600, CurrentTime)
    'Following three lines are added for copying the first row of source sheet to target sheet. you may remove it.
    sourceSheet.Rows(2).Copy
    targetSheet.Rows(targetRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    targetRow = targetRow + 1
    
    For currentRow = 2 To lastRow
        currentTime = sourceSheet.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
        
        ' Check if the value in column B is a valid time
        If IsDate(currentTime) Then
            currentTime = TimeValue(currentTime)
            
            ' Check if the time matches the 10-minute interval (00:00:00, 00:10:00, etc.)
            'If (Hour(currentTime) Mod 10 = 0 And Minute(currentTime) = 0 And Second(currentTime) = 0) Then
'            If (CurrentTime = NextTime) Then ** it does not work at change of hours
            If (Format(CurrentTime, "DD-Mmm-YYYY hh-nn-ss") = Format(NextTime, "DD-Mmm-YYYY hh-nn-ss")) Then
                NextTime = DateAdd("s", 600, CurrentTime)
                ' Copy the entire row where the time in column B matches the interval
                sourceSheet.Rows(currentRow).Copy
                targetSheet.Rows(targetRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                targetRow = targetRow + 1  ' Move to the next target row in Sheet1
            End If
        End If
    Next currentRow
    
    ' Save and close workbooks
    targetWB.Save
    
    MsgBox "Data filtered and copied in 10-minute intervals."
End Sub

I implemented procedure in Microsoft Excel 2016.
Thank you.

This code only copies the data in this time interval 0:10:00,0:20:00,0:30:00,0:40:00,0:50:00. I have data with the time intervals of 0:00:00 to 23:59:55.
